# How to label encode multiple categories (multiple rows) in order with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, scikit-learn

I have a pandas dataframe (in python) and I would like to label encode two columns ready for training a machine learning model on. Turning it from categorical data to numeric. (I am not looking to OneHotEncode the data just yet)

---

I have a dataframe with similar data (once ordered) to this:

```
Main_Category    Sub_Category
Cat_0            Sub_1
Cat_1            Cub_1
Cat_1            Aub_2
Cat_2            Sub_3
```

The data follows the following relationship where a main category can have many unique sub categories. I would like to first order the dataframe by Main_Category then by Sub_Category. This would group all of the sub categories together by their main category.

```
df = df.sort_values(['Main_Category', 'Sub_Category'], ascending=[True, True])
```

---

I would then like to encode the data so that it looked like this:

```
Main_Category    Sub_Category
0                0
1                1
1                2
2                3
```

However, when I do encode the data I get it encoded like this:

```
Main_Category    Sub_Category
0                2
1                0
1                1
2                3
```

I believe that the encoding library is sorting the data itself then encoding based on those results. I would like it to encode based on my own sorting. What would be the ideal solution for this?

This is the code for encoding the columns:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
df['Main_Category'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(df['Main_Category'])
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
df['Sub_Category'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(df['Sub_Category'])
```

---

Edit: I cannot show the real data and that is why my question has dummy data.
Edit: Updated the sub_category names to better show the error

Comment: Don't use same `labelencoder` for different columns. That will override what it had learned previously. Instantiate `LabelEncoder` as many times as the columns you want to encode.

Comment: Thanks for your input Chris. I have updated my question to reflect this. While that is an error in my code the result is still undesired. I believe that when you give the sklearn library the array to encode, that it sorts it itself (undoing my sort) and then returning the labels.

Comment: Your editted version is nevertheless the same. You are assigning to the same variable, overwriting the former `LabelEncoder`. Try something like `le1, le2, ...`

Comment: As for the _real issue_, I cannot reproduce it. Can you reproduce it with given examplary data?

Comment: I have updated the question by renaming the sub-categories. Using this data and the same code shown I still get the undesired results. Renaming the label encoder doesnt have any impact.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you mentioned, `labelencoder` does sorting [internally](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7389dba/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py#L257).
If you want to make the encoding to happen in the specific order then use `_encode`
directly.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing.label import _encode

unique_main_cat, ind = np.unique(df.Main_Category, return_index=True) 

# unique_main_cat would have sorted unique values,  
# to get the original order use argmin(ind)

_encode(df['Main_Category'], 
        uniques=unique_main_cat[np.argsort(ind)], 
        encode=True)

# (array(['Cat_0', 'Cat_1', 'Cat_2'], dtype=object), array([0, 1, 1, 2]))



unique_sub_cat, ind = np.unique(df.Sub_Category, return_index=True)
_encode(df['Sub_Category'], 
        uniques=unique_sub_cat[np.argsort(ind)], 
        encode=True)

# (array(['Sub_1', 'Aub_2', 'Cub_1', 'Sub_3'], dtype=object), array([0, 1, 2, 3]))
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering. There is errors when trying to import that library. I tried importing LabelEncoder instead but that doesnt work with this code?

Comment: If you upgrade your sklearn version to 0.20, it will work I think. Otherwise, can you share your error message